# Samsung galaxy i9000 switching off on its own like a gazillion times a day

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I have been a proud owner of a samsung galaxy i9000 for about a year now. However, my phone recently developed a problem that I had not anticipated. The phone now just switches off on its own. Sometimes it can do so up to 5 times a day. One moment the phone will be working and you go on with whatever you will be doing and before you know it the phone is off. The phone cannot be restarted using the normal on and off button. I actually have to remove the battery and put it back for the phone to restart again. Anyone with a clue?

Comment: Does this happen only when the phone is idle, or does it shut itself off while you are actively using it (e.g. during phone calls, web browsing, game playing, etc.?)

Comment: Overheating, perhaps? Or corroded connectors on the battery?

Comment: V-T-C as its TL?